# Reduce size of \bullet character in lists

Tags: symbols, lists, fontsize

Example for a list using `mdwlist`:

```
\begin{itemize*}
\item First
\item Second
\end{itemize*}
```

The bullet symbol for the first level can be redefined with:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
```

It apparently uses a math environments symbol by default.
I would like to reduce the size of it, but font size modifiers like `\tiny` seem to be invalid.

Answer (score 16):

For centering material vertically you can use `\vcenter`, but this only works in math mode. Thus you need to enter math mode twice:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
```

Comment: Well, this comes at last. The only disadvantage may be that it's not so friendly for most LaTeX users. How about `\parbox[c]{.5em}{\tiny\textbullet}`? It needs an extra width, but should be OK here.

Answer (score 3):

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{{\tiny$\bullet$}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it corrupts the vertical alignment of bullet and text. So I guess the font size should not be changed, instead I need another character with a smaller symbol.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion to use `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{{\tiny$\bullet$}}` actually seems to leave the alignment alone, in that the baseline of the bullet is the baseline of the text.  If you'd like to raise it, though, you can use

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage that you have to do trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

In case that a tiny bullet is a specific demand, you could use the `\textperiodcentered` command from the [textcomp](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package in conjunction with the [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package for a compact list.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}[label=\textperiodcentered,nolistsep]
    \item First
    \item Second
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```