# Suppress left indentation in itemize environment

Tags: itemize

I used itemize code as follows:
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}, and the assoicated results are displayed as:
[image]

But I want no left indentation about the round point mark. I want the following results which produced in Word editor:
[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To reduce the size of the symbol used (`\textbullet`), you can use `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,label=\scalebox{.8}{\textbullet}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am so surprised that I got the exact answer in just a minute. Thanks very much! Another question I want to ask is how to change the size of the round point  mark.

Comment: Well, it's almost holiday season, so perhaps that might explain why response took a whole minute this time. :-) To answer your question perhaps [Reduce size of \bullet character in lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86336/adding-right-aligned-text-in-a-paragraph) might help.

Comment: @user22986 I updated my answer providing a possible solution to the new requirement.

Comment: @PeterGrill the link you provided links to a different question not related to the bullet size.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I cut and pasted from the wrong tab. Here is the one I was referring to : [Reduce size of \bullet character in lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8510/reduce-size-of-bullet-character-in-lists).